# use of operation type Pos under inventory management

Tags: odoo

I have utilized the Point of Sale (POS) system for sales transactions and encountered an issue. Despite completing some successful sales via POS, I noticed that the corresponding quantities were not accurately subtracted from the inventory. Upon investigation within the Inventory module, I observed an unprocessed entry marked as "1" under the POS Order section.

I am seeking clarity regarding the specific criteria causing only certain sales made through the POS to be linked to this unprocessed entry. Additionally, I am curious about the need for manual validation in this scenario.

Your assistance in shedding light on these matters would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help.

[image]